# yii lucene index doesn't exists

Tags: zend-framework, yii, lucene

I want to do the SearchBox on my webapp. I followed tutorial: [SeachBox Tutorial](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/248/adding-search-to-yii-blog-example-using-zend-lucene/) excatly, did everything author mentioned, and I'm getting an error:

> Index doesn't exists in the specified directory.

My SearchController:

```
  <?php
class SearchController extends Controller
{
private $_indexFiles = 'runtime.search';

public function init(){
    Yii::import('application.vendors.*');
    require_once('Zend/Search/Lucene.php');
    parent::init(); 
}

/**
 * Search index creation
 */
public function actionCreate()
{
    $index = Zend_Search_Lucene::create($_indexFiles);
    $index = new Zend_Search_Lucene(Yii::getPathOfAlias('application.' . $this->_indexFiles), true);

    $posts = News::model()->findAll();
    foreach($news as $news){
        $doc = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Document();

        $doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::Text('title',
                                      CHtml::encode($news->name), 'utf-8')
        );

        $doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::Text('link',
                                        CHtml::encode($news->url)
                                            , 'utf-8')
        );   

        $doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::Text('content',
                                      CHtml::encode($news->description)
                                      , 'utf-8')
        );


        $index->addDocument($doc);
    }
    $index->commit();
    echo 'Lucene index created';
}

public function actionSearch()
{
    $this->layout='column2';
     if (($term = Yii::app()->getRequest()->getParam('q', null)) !== null) {
        $index = new Zend_Search_Lucene(Yii::getPathOfAlias('application.' . $this->_indexFiles));
        $results = $index->find($term);
        $query = Zend_Search_Lucene_Search_QueryParser::parse($term);       

        $this->render('search', compact('results', 'term', 'query'));
    }
}
```

}

Any ideas to solve this problem? Thanks for any help.

EDIT: OK, the solution was quite obvious. Index wasn't writed because it wasn't really declared...

this **private $_indexFiles = 'runtime.search';** before init should just be in actionCreate function - then it works

Thanks for your help!

Comment: sorry, missed that. private $_indexFiles = 'runtime/search';

Comment: and does the folder exists?

Comment: yes runtime/search does exists

Comment: seems to be. but everytime I deselect "read-only" in properties and apply it, then again going to properties, it is like partly selected and creating empty "read.lock.file" in search folder

Comment: OK, the solution was quite obvious. Index wasn't writed because it wasn't really declared...

this *private $_indexFiles = 'runtime.search';* before init should just be in actionCreate function - then it works

Thanks for your help!

Comment: you are right, it was a typo xD

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo:

```
$posts = News::model()->findAll();
foreach($news as $news){
```

Should be:

```
$posts = News::model()->findAll();
foreach($posts as $news){
```